# How to get plain javascript array from realm object proxy list?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, es6-proxy

**Scenario:**

For ex, you define a schema in realm-js as:

```
export const businessSchema = {
  name: 'Business',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    number_of_stores_in_cities: 'int[]',
  }
}
```

You have already created an object of `Business` and saved to Realm. Then have queried this object somewhere else. And you want to copy this field `number_of_stores_in_cities` to javascript array `js_number_of_store_in_cities` for further processing.

**What I expect:**  Realm has defined handlers to get the entire target list which I can simply call it like `number_of_stores_in_cities.all()` or `number_of_stores_in_cities.getList()` in the `Proxy`

**What I have:** Seems like they didn't define these handlers for what I expect. And their getters are defined based on index of an array. So this proxy `number_of_stores_in_cities` works exactly like a javascript array. I tried to copy entries one by one from `number_of_stores_in_cities` to `js_number_of_stores_in_cities`.  I've also tried `const js_number_of_stores_in_cities = Array.prototype.slice.call(number_of_stores_in_cities)`. However, both of the methods are unexpectedly slow such that they took roughly 10 seconds to copy a length of 2500 list.

**What I need:** Instead of using these traditional javascript array methods, is there a way that I can get a plain javascript array from the `Proxy` in a fast fashion? Do I need to provide my handler to this `Proxy`?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Array.from(number_of_stores_in_cities)`? Haven't tried the method myself with a huge number of List elements, so can't comment on the performance, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've tried that before asking this question, no luck, still unexpectedly slow.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Basically I just need to know the correct name of the `[[Target]]` or `[[Handler]]` so that I can get the entire list from the `Proxy`

Comment: @LingboTang facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @KaranPatyal Not yet, if I found I'll post a solution here.

Comment: @LingboTang did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: @JohnK No, it's almost unable to add your own getter in the proxy unless Realm team modify their own core function. This functionality is still under discussion on their issue tracker: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/280

Comment: Any solution to this ?